# How to save the current user for the created model object in Django rest framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have this model which used to create a article and the article has a field which associated to the Django user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    pub_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # fields need to be added
        # location 
        # byline -> line tells who writes the article 
        # conclusion
        # tags


    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

I use the Django rest framework view to create the object. Using Postman and giving the author id, I can create the article post:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data = request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What I need to achieve is the only the logged user need to be able to create the article and when the user create the article the author id need to be auto updated at the time the object was created.

Here is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Article

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields  = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use permission decorator with IsAuthenticated permission to allow only the authenticated users as the following:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def create(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(data = request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The above code will allow only the authenticated users to use that view now to take the value of the user id from the logged-in user directly without sending it in the body request you can do the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializer
from .models import Article

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['author']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Get the authenticated user from the request
        user = self.context['request'].user

        # Add the authenticated user as the author of the article
        validated_data['author'] = user

        # Create the article with the updated data
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: for the authentication part is working but still i get the key error request in create

Comment: Can you show the error message
But I think you need to add .id to the user 
user = self.context['request'].user.id

Comment: `KeyError at /news/create/
'request'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/news/create/
Django Version: 4.2.3
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'request'`

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. The context object will not be filled if you call the serializer by itself in the class-based view It usually gets loaded when you call self.get_serializer(data=request.data) but since you are using a function-based theory, you should base the context by yourself
 serializer = ArticleSerializer(data = request.data, context={"request": request})

Comment: Thank you i found it. what if i need to validate the user on delete method? how can i accomplish that?

Comment: If you mean only the article owner who can delete then you can do that using a custom permission class like the following 

from rest_framework import permissions
class RecordOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        if request.user.id == None:

            return False
        else:
            return request.user.id == obj.author.id

Then just use it as the IsAuthenticated permission using the decorator